# If you leave now / If you are leaving now

Tags: if

What's the difference between these sentences?
Of course, I know about Present Simple & Present Progressive. )

As I understand these sentences, I can translate them similarly. But there must be a slight nuance, mustn't there? Please, explain this nuance (with "If").

> **If you leave now**, you will be able to catch the 5 o'clock train.
>
> **If you are leaving now**, you will be able to catch the 5 o'clock train.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my comment has been upvoted, I'll convert it to an answer.

The first one sounds like a recommendation to leave now in order to catch the train. 'If you are leaving now...' suggests that the person addressed has shown signs of wanting to leave (getting belongings together, putting coat on or whatever).